# Upload the file on localhost so anyone in network can access

Tags: html, wamp

I have created a html file that I am trying to host on the localhost using wamp server so that anyone in the network can access it I have also updated the hosts file to

```
172.x.x.x www.kpcl.com
```

This works fine what, when anyone with this hosts file tries to access my page thing is person has to type `www.kpcl.com/checkl.html` where checkl.html is my file situated in www folder of wamp
in the url section I want that as soon as the person enters the `www.kpcl.com` **by default the checkl.html** page gets loaded what to do?

Answer (score -3):

You'd have to alter the .htaccess file to read check1.html as the document root of kpcl.com. Normally pages named `home.*` or `index.*` are the first ones that a browser reads. Since you don't have it named either of those, and since it's probably not the only file in that directory, it doesn't know what to open.

[This should help](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/htaccess-change-index-page) (near the bottom).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14081509)

Comment: So sorry. That's my mistake.